# How to show route in Apple maps with multiple points in iOS

Tags: ios, mapkit, apple-maps

I have a route with multiple points (more than 2), how can I open Apple maps app and show it?

I know it is possible to show route between 2 points:

```
let mapItems = [MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinat1, addressDictionary: nil)),
                MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinat2, addressDictionary: nil))]
MKMapItem.openMaps(with: mapItems, launchOptions: [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving])
```

But it supports only two points. I'm also aware this can be achieved using Google maps using such url:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/<lat>,<lng>/<lat>,<lng>/.../.../
```

But I can find similar solution for Apple Maps

EDIT: Since I can show Apple maps like this as well:

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)&dirflg=d")!)
```

Maybe there is some sort of way to pass more coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

As MKMapItem documentation states:

> If you specify the MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey option in the
>   launchOptions dictionary, the mapItems array must have no more than
>   two items in it. If the array contains one item, the Maps app
>   generates directions from the user’s current location to the location
>   specified by the map item. If the array contains two items, the Maps
>   app generates directions from the location of the first item to the
>   location of the second item in the array.

So the answer is no.

Comment: the slightly longer answer is perhaps.  If you have enough points to define the path, then you can display the route as an overlay using MKPolyline and MKPolylineRenderer

Comment: @MoinShirazi I guess I should have added not only the example, but Apple documentation as well, as my example was intended to acknowledge `MKMapItem` limitations.
I've added an edit.
-
@Russell, yes I could, but you see, I do need turn-by-turn navigation, so drawing route my self is out of the question.